# Unable to install scipy offline in docker

Tags: python, docker, scipy

I downloaded scipy 1.12.0 on my local linux machine with internet using

> pip download scipy -d "/home/Documents"

scipy-1.12.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl

and i copied the whl files into my docker path called /tf/work.
Inside my docker (without internet connection intentionally), i have a pip version of

> pip 23.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pip (python 3.11)

when i try to enter this command to install my scipy offline

> pip install scipy --no-index -f "/tf/work"

The error messages shows "Error could not find a version that satifies the requirement scipy." May i know what am i doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you're trying to use a cp310 wheel with cp311. You'll need a cp311 wheel. From the `/tf/work` directory, and assuming that you've activated the correct env, I would do `pip install scipy-1.12.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Your python version is Python 3.11 and as @Andrew Nelson mentioned in the comments, you are trying to use a cp310 wheel with cp311.

What you need is the cp311 wheel and you can get it here [scipy-1.12.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/b8/7169935f9a2ea9e274ad8c21d6133d492079e6ebc3fc69a915c2375616b0/scipy-1.12.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl)